# Best way to find retain cycle?

Tags: ios, memory-management

I have a nasty retain cycle in my iOS app. I'm looking at it in instruments and can see all of the retains/releases, but it's hard to track down exactly which retain is the one still holding on.

Does anyone have advice for finding exactly which retain is holding onto the reference?

Edit: Picture of the retain/releases:

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of instruments with the retain cycle?

Comment: Added. If you do find it, I'd love to learn how. I have read a guide or two about the most common causes of retain cycles (delegates, timers, blocks...) but what I'm really interested in is learning how to find them without doing an intense code review. Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, run Analyzer.  If that doesn't do it, use instruments to figure out what objects are in the cycle and look where you work with those.  "Intense code review" is something of a given, unless you get lucky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out if instruments detects the leak, like so:
[image]

From the looks of it, though, that timer near the end of the list doesn't get released.
Could you update your post with the code in `setVideoState` ?

Edit:

What I usually do is try and match up the retain/releases (instruments should actually do that for you, i think it was some filter in the menu to the left), while focusing on my code, because the frameworks usually have their things together. In your case, as you go down that list you see that the timer has +1 but never get released after that.

Comment: Hey Andrew -- You got it, it was timers. I had an issue because I release the timers in dealloc, but dealloc never is called because of the timers. I am going to remove the timers on viewdiddisappear and re-add them on viewdidappear, since I am using a nav controller. Would you recommend that?

Comment: Also, could you update your answer just a bit with your process for finding this? That is what my real question is about. I'll mark it as the answer after. Thanks.

Comment: Without know more about your project, the approach that you've chosen sounds good, if you can do it before that - go for it. Are you doing something based on how much time has elapsed in a video? Either way, I've updated my post with the method I used to deduce the leak.